# Inserting data in postgres with bookshelf ORM nodejs, getting error as relation does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js, bookshelf.js

Inserting records, with bookshelf..
But getting bad luck on inserting, getting err as give below:

```
let {mobile, email, name, active=1} = req.body
  let insert = {
    'mobile_number': mobile,
    'email_id': email,
    'name': name,
    'status': 1
  }
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve(
      MarketDetails.create(insert)
    );
  });
```

**SchoolDetails**

```
var modelBase = require('./bookshelf');

var MarketDetails = modelBase.extend({
  tableName: 'market',
  hasTimestamps: true
});

module.exports = MarketDetails;
```

Getting ERROR Details as:

(node:68399) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): error: insert into "market" ("status", "created_at", "email_id", "mobile_number", "name", "updated_at") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) returning "id" - column "updated_at" of relation "market" does not exist

Please help if any..

Comment: Looks like you are trying to reference "updated_at" column in your "market" table which the error is saying does not exist. Does your table have this column?

Comment: Yes it has in market table

Answer (score 0):

I have made **Timestamps** property as false!
Works for me.. All we need key column id as well in table..

By default, Eloquent will maintain the created_at and updated_at columns on your database table automatically. Simply add these timestamp columns to your table and Eloquent will take care of the rest. If you do not wish for Eloquent to maintain these columns, add the following property to your model:

```
hasTimestamps: false
```